# rc.local to be executed at boot

Tags: boot

I got this question in a test

> Alter the init boot sequence so that the rc.local or
>   boot.local script (depending on the distribution that you have
>   selected) is executed at boot time.

I had trouble with it. 
Could anyone give a hand on this.

Comment: See `/etc/init.d/rc.local`

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu (or debian based) has a boot process that you can find in `/etc/init.d/`.  Other mayor branches (Fedora, Suse) tend to have their own method though. You can find a `rc.local` in there that has a remark about it running `/etc/rc.local` **if present**. That is the one you probably are expected to create.

In `/etc/rc.local` you can put scripts to be executed at a run-level.

Example file with 1 line added:

```
$ more /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

[ -x /sbin/initctl ] && initctl emit --no-wait google-rc-local-has-run || true

exit 0
```

Comment: Alright, so, in simple words, any script located in init.d will run at boot.

Comment: @CleverAraya It's almost that simple -- scripts go into /etc/init.d, and then symlinks in /etc/rc* point at the scripts in /etc/.init.d.  Google for "sysvinit" for more info.